# Jenkins pointing server to domain created

Tags: jenkins

Good Morning

I have created a Jenkins server in AWS I am able to access the platform using the IP of the server
however, I want to access it more securely.

I have set up a subdomain on my hosting service and I set the IP of the server as an A record
I have also defined this in the configuration section of Jenkins

however, when I access the URL https://domainname I get nothing
but if I add 8080 at the end of it it takes me to the Jenkins platform

what am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use AWS Application Load Balancer to access to you jenkins web server.

I will host https certificat (if you are using AWS Certificate Manager) and you will be able configure DNS to redirect to ALB name.